# Why Ubuntu prefers RA route to directly connected interface?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, routing, ipv6

I have the following topology:
[image]

There is 2 routers `OTBR1` and `OTBR2` that have an interface `wpan0` connected to the same
`fd71:f19:d5f5:1::/64` network.

- They both advertise this route through RA on the `fd04:2240::/48` segment.
- They both receive each other RA and add a route.

In their routing table, the kernel added a route through `wpan0` with a metric of `256` as expected:

```
fd71:f19:d5f5:1::/64 dev wpan0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

However it actually prefer the RA route with a metric of `100`:

```
fd71:f19:d5f5:1::/64 via fe80::dea6:32ff:fe52:6bbc dev eno1 proto ra metric 100 expires 1522sec pref medium
```

This is actual chaos because both routers prefer sending the packet to the other one and so the packet will never actually enter the `fd71:f19:d5f5:1::/64` segment.

Any idea why Ubuntu would prefer an RA route to a directly connected interface?

Answer (score 2):

The OS used in this issue is `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` which is using `systemd-networkd 249.11-0ubuntu3.4`.

According to the man page, it should not add RA with a metric of 100. It should be 1024 by default:

> Set the routing metric for the routes received in the Router Advertisement. Takes an unsigned integer in the range 0...4294967295. Defaults to 1024.

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/systemd.network.5.html

My guess is that they changed the default in an Ubuntu patch to mimic the behavior of NetworkManager.

I was hoping to get confirmation here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452642/what-overrides-ipv6acceptra-routemetric-defaults

Something like this can be used to re-apply the defaults which to me makes a lot more sense as an RA route, even with high priority, will never supersede a directly connected interface:

```bash
cat /etc/systemd/network/05-eno1.network 
[Match]
Name=eno1

[IPv6AcceptRA]
RouteMetric="512:1024:2048"
```